# How to position header and footer fixed in mobile browser

Tags: css, mobile, browser

I'm working on a website to make compatible with mobile browser. So I would set header and footer fixed and this worked fine on desktop browser, but when I open in android browser for example, the header scroll and the footer not.... how is it possible?
The website example is: http://www.mimanchitu.it/prova/

Comment: please always append your code in the question

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do that is with Jquery or Javascript.
You need to calculate the height of the screen, then you calculate the height of the header and footer and after you quit all that, you will have the height of the content.

Something like this:

```
var screenHeight=$(window).height();
var headerHeight=$("#idHeade").height();
var footerHeight=$("#idFooter").height();
var total=screenHeight-headerHeight-footerHeight;

$("#content").css("height",total);
```

then you put to the content a scrool, and that's all. I use that for a App with phonegap, and works perfect.

Comment: but i dont understand the difference between the mobile browser! And why the footer stay fixed and the header not!

Comment: Are you using JqueryMobile? or just the CSS?

Comment: I use jquery normal version, not for mobile! I dont like it! Is there a solution with js or similar?

Comment: The solution I'm give to you is a solution with js, I ask if you was using Jquery Mbile, 'cause that is a comun problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS

```
#header, #footer {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("footer").style.position = "fixed";
```

Worked for me!

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to do this. CSS has media queries.